# Configure Apache to forward dynamic page requests to Tomcat in friendly url scenarios

Tags: apache, tomcat, apache-config

I have a website with friendly urls.

I want all url´s that end with .htm, .gif, .jpg, .css, .js be served directly by the Apache web server and the rest passed on to Tomcat.

examples of dynamic url´s that should be forwarded to Tomcat:

```
www.mysite.com/news/newsItem1
www.mysite.com/videos
www.mysite.com/news/list.jsp
```

examples of static url´s on the same site that should be served by Apache:

```
www.mysite.com/news/newsItem2.htm
www.mysite.com/image1.gif
```

Using the jk_module I figured out how to configure JkMount to forward extensions like .jsp to Tomcat... however what I am looking for is a not operator in the url so that I can specify something like: if url not ending with .htm or .gif or .jpg or .css or .js then forward to Tomcat.

Any ideas as to how I can do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example from the [mod_jk documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/webserver_howto/apache.html):

```
# All requests go to worker1 by default
JkMount /* worker1
# Serve html, jpg and gif using httpd
JkUnMount /*.html worker1
JkUnMount /*.jpg  worker1
JkUnMount /*.gif  worker1
```

You can easily generalize it to your needs.

Comment: Thanks so much.  It is great when answers are simple like this one. You have no idea how much this information helps me.